# Unknown errors when posting user input texts

Tags: php, html

I am trying to write a webpage in PHP to process a line of texts or a .txt file uploaded by the user but the corresponding dimension in `$_POST` never get updated properly. Please see the following screenshot.[image: screenshot].

I do not recognize this error and guess it may be related to the max input size. Since all of my input tabs are under the same `form`, and the uploaded .txt file can always be processed properly, I have no ideas why the string texted by the user never goes to `$_POST`. Codes for this part is like: (by the way what is covered in the screenshot is the path of this .php file in the server)

```
<form id ..., name = name1, enctype = "multipart/form-data" action ... method = "post" nonvalidate>

  <div> 
    <label for = 'line'> ... </label>
    <input id = ... name = 'line' type = 'text' ...>
  </div>
  ...
  <div>
    <label for = 'file'> ... </label>
    <input id =  ... name = 'file' type = 'file'>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button id = ... name = 'submit'>Submit</button>
  </div>

</form>

...

<h1>Result of Processing the input line</h1>
  <?php 
    echo var_dump($_POST).'<br>';
    ...
  ?>
```

If anyone recognize this error it would be great to hear more details from you. This is the main reason why I was block and now I do not know which part to debug ...

Comment: Try posting the code without the unnecessary obfuscations of the id or labels. I am not understanding the issue as you have explained it. The `var_dump($_POST)` is displaying the `asd, qwe, 123` text from the form submission. This may be a browser specific/invalid HTML issue. Some issues I see is with inconsistent single/double quotes for html attributes and one attribute missing quotes with erroneous commas `id ..., name = name1,` should be `id = "id" name = "name1"`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried using double quotes for all attributes but it made no differences but could you explain why this will be a problem? I shall at least keep the ```class``` attribute and the ```name``` so that it would be easier to edit the style and find values in ```$_POST```

Comment: The big issue I saw was with the commas separating the HTML attributes, but without the actual code I cannot validate if something you removed or added in your question is the issue. As for why it is an issue - browsers utilize different engines to process the HTML code into a DOM. For example FireFox uses Mozilla, IE uses Trident, Google uses Safari-Webkit. Each have their own "quirks" on how they render the code. Some will remove elements, others fix erroneous HTML automatically, etc. For example IE has issues with `type="submit" id="submit" name="submit"`

Comment: Thanks for all the details. I will keep on tryin other methods